# micropython usocket.IPPROTO_SEC not available

Tags: python, sockets, micropython, usocket

I tried using **usocket.IPPROTO_SEC** for micropython however it does not seem available.
Is there anything else I should do to get access to **usocket.IPPROTO_SEC**?

**Setup**

I use [this](https://hub.docker.com/r/mitchins/micropython-linux) docker image.

Micropython version: **1.11**

**Description**

The micropython docs say that [usocket.IPPROTO_SEC](https://docs.micropython.org/en/latest/library/usocket.html#usocket.IPPROTO_SEC) is an available constant, however when I try to access it, it is not there.

The output below shows how I am trying to access it and what are the attributes available inside usocket.

```sh
MicroPython v1.11-10-g84f1067f7 on 2019-06-02; linux version
Use Ctrl-D to exit, Ctrl-E for paste mode
>>> import usocket
>>> usocket.IPPROTO_SEC
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'IPPROTO_SEC'
>>> usocket.
__class__       __name__        AF_INET         AF_INET6
AF_UNIX         MSG_DONTROUTE   MSG_DONTWAIT    SOCK_DGRAM
SOCK_RAW        SOCK_STREAM     SOL_SOCKET      SO_BROADCAST
SO_ERROR        SO_KEEPALIVE    SO_LINGER       SO_REUSEADDR
getaddrinfo     inet_ntop       inet_pton       sockaddr
socket
```

Comment: The section of the documentation that you linked to is clearly marked "Constants specific to WiPy", which is a specific hardware platform.

Comment: I saw the reference. The way I interpreted is that the main micropython lib would have these constants but they would only take effect on specific hardware. When installing micropython from micropython-lib is there a way to specify the wipy feature set?

Comment: I would guess that the WiPy module has built-in hardware support for SSL, and that micropython's support consists solely of knowing how to use that hardware (rather than a software-only implementation of SSL that would work on arbitrary platforms).  Having even the constant available on other platforms would therefore be a waste of space.